A question on an equivalent form of Kalmar hierarchy
In the book named A Course on Borel Sets by Srivastava, the set of all  clopen subsets of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is given as in the following screenshot. However, the book doesn't provide with a definition for section for such sets. What could be the definition? Additionally, I couldn't find any info for Kalmar hierarchy on the web. Is there any source that I can learn about it?

You're not the first to stumble upon this, see here.

The author seems to be a little bit sloppy: also the inductive definition of the set $\mathcal A_\alpha$ doesn't make sense as the set $A$ to be contained in $\mathcal A_\alpha$ doesn't occur on the right-hand side anymore. Probably, it should read as something like "for all sections $A_i$ of $A$" (whatever this obscure "section" means).

This is somewhat nonstandard terminology, but I have seen it used a few times: for $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and $i\in\mathbb{N}$, we let $$A_i=\{f\in\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}: i^\smallfrown f\in A\},$$ where $i^\smallfrown f$ is the sequence gotten by prepending $i$ to $f$ (that is, $i^\smallfrown f(0)=i$ and $i^\smallfrown f(n+1)=f(n)$).
The intuition is that a clopen set is "built" by gluing to each leaf $\sigma$ of some well-founded tree $T$ a label $l_\sigma\in\{Y,N\}$; if $l_\sigma=Y$ then all sequences extending $\sigma$ are in the clopen set, and if $l_\sigma= N$ then none of the sequences extending $\sigma$ are in the open set. The inductive construction described in the OP basically keeps track of the rank of the tree $T$ involved in this definition.
